# Passing a file as a command line argument and reading its lines

Tags: java, file, command-line

this is the code that i have found in the internet for reading the lines of a file and also I use eclipse and I passed the name of files as SanShin.txt in its argument field. but it will print :

```
Error: textfile.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Code:

```
public class Zip {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            // Open the file that is the first 
            // command line parameter
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console
              System.out.println (strLine);
            }
            //Close the input stream
            in.close();
            }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
              System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }


    }
}
```

please help me why it prints this error.
thanks

Comment: also this is the location of my project:C:\Documents and Settings\icc\workspace\Hoffman Project

Comment: and my text file is in desktop.

Comment: the args are not used by your program: it always opens textfile.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
...
// command line parameter
if(argv.length != 1) {
  System.err.println("Invalid command line, exactly one argument required");
  System.exit(1);
}

try {
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(argv[0]);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}

// Get the object of DataInputStream
...

> java -cp ... Zip \path\to\test.file
```

Comment: How should you initialize `argv`? Can you use `args` instead?

Comment: It's a typo, I believe argv is being used in Python. You should use args[0] here.

Answer (score 1):

Your `new FileInputStream("textfile.txt")` is correct. If it's throwing that exception, there is no `textfile.txt` in the current directory when you run the program. Are you sure the file's name isn't actually `testfile.txt` (note the `s`, not `x`, in the third position).

---

**Off-topic**: But your earlier deleted question asked how to read a file line by line (I didn't think you needed to delete it, FWIW). On the assumption you're still a beginner and getting the hang of things, a pointer: You probably **don't** want to be using `FileInputStream`, which is for binary files, but instead use the [`Reader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) set of interfaces/classes in [`java.io`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) (including [`FileReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)). Also, whenever possible, declare your variables using the interface, even when initializing them to a specific class, so for instance, `Reader r = new FileReader("textfile.txt")` (rather than `FileReader r = ...`).

Answer (score 1):

When you just specify `"textfile.txt"` the operating system will look in the program's working directory for that file.

You can specify the absolute path to the file with something like `new FileInputStream("C:\\full\\path\\to\\file.txt")`

Also if you want to know the directory your program is running in, try this:
`System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath())`