# Reading file input from Java using terminal

Tags: java

I have a Java file Animal.java, and I want to be able to write a terminal command like so:

> java Animal -a -print < data.txt

I know that the `-a` and `-print` appear as variables in the array `arg` (which is an input to the `main` method -- so `arg[0]` is `-a` and `arg[1]` is `-print`), but how can I access the data from `data.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

It's is not possible in java, but instead you may pass the location of the file(not required if its already known and fixed) and then access the file's data using InputStream/ readLine() etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate the files in the same way that the Unix pipes do. You need treat your arguments so that there is a prefix or a position that defines the name of the file you want to read, so it is possible read the file passed as argument.

```
// Treating arguments and verify the possibility of reading file
// Get index which is the file name
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream (argv [FileIndex]);
// Handle the file .
```

See an example here: [Passing a file as a command line argument and reading its lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302567/passing-a-file-as-a-command-line-argument-and-reading-its-lines)

Answer (score -1):

Imagina the structure `src/mypack/Main.java`, run on terminal:

```
$ cd src/mypack/
/src/mypack$ javac Main.java 
/src/mypack$ cd ..
/src$ java mypack.Main < path/your/file
```

Comment: this answer doesn't address the user's question. He wants to know how to access the input from `data.txt` in his program.