# How to handle "<" in args from terminal input in java

Tags: java

//possible duplicate: [Reading file input from Java using terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157945/reading-file-input-from-java-using-terminal)

For my uni assignment I have to read data input from the console. This is the example input: java MyClass -x < file.txt

**My problem is**: In Eclipse the output for args.length is 3 -> "-x", "<", "file.txt", but when I try this in my console (javac MyClass.java and then run), it says that args.length is 1.

How do I handle "<" in java so I can access "file.txt" correctly?

My code:

```
System.out.println(args.length); // eclipse says 3, console says 1
String param1 = args[0] // -x
String param2 = args[1] // <
String param3 = args[2] // file.txt
```

Comment: `<` is the shell redirection operator so it won't appear in the argument list

Comment: The `<` symbol is likely handled by the OS and not visible to Java. To make it visible, you may have to enclose the command line parameters in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. So eclipse can access this "<", but by default it isn't accessible? But if I ignore it and just say args[1] is file.txt, it won't correctly run in eclipse...

Comment: Don't run it in eclipse.  Run it from the command line.  I don't know how Eclipse pass the arguments to the class.  I suspect it is passed as three arguments:  "-x" "<" "file.txt".