# Passing commands to program as a text file

Tags: java, linux, terminal

I'm trying to pass the commands in to my program as a text file. I've created a file named *commands_in_english.txt* and have tried passing in the instructions but it's giving me an error message. Not sure if I'm passing in the file wrong or if I'm missing something in my text file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The commands should be passed in to the program as a file with one instruction per line. The English instructions are in *thefile commands_in_english.txt*. I've called the program by the passing in the instructions as follows:

```
java ConsoleRobot < commands_in_english.txt
```

This is the program I'm trying to pass the commands to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConsoleRobot extends SmarterRobot
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      World yard = new World();

  SmarterRobot ringo = new SmarterRobot();
  yard.add(ringo,5,4);

  yard.addBeeper(5,9);
  yard.addBeeper(4,5);

  yard.addBeeper(9,4);
  yard.addBeeper(9,5);

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a command: | Introduzca un comando:");
  String command = scan.nextLine();
  command = command.toLowerCase();

        while (!command.equals("stop") && !command.equals("detener"))
  {
  System.out.println("command = "+command);

  if ( command.equals("forward") || command.equals("adelante"))
  {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How far should the robot move?"); 
        int input = reader.nextInt();  
        ringo.moveNumOfTimes(input);
      }

      else if ( command.equals("right") || command.equals("derecha"))
   {
       ringo.turnRight();
       }

       else if ( command.equals("left") || command.equals("izquierda"))
  {
     ringo.turnLeft();
      }

       else if ( command.equals("collect") || command.equals("recoger"))
      {
    ringo.pickBeeper();
      }

   else if ( command.equals("drop") || command.equals("soltar"))
   {
    ringo.putBeeper();
   }

      else
   {
     System.out.println("I don't understand! | No entiendo!");
   }

      System.out.println("Enter a command: | Introduzca un comando:");
  command = scan.nextLine();
}
    System.out.println("Finished | Terminado");

   }
}
```

Comment: can u show ur code base to understand wat ur trying to achieve as a whole

Comment: Your current syntax attempts to pass the content of the file to the application's input stream (`System.in`), not as parameters to the `main` method .

Comment: you can not pass into a Java program a file as a Argument but you can pass its path... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302567/passing-a-file-as-a-command-line-argument-and-reading-its-lines

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, when you want to pass a configuration file for a program you dont have use "<".

Try to pass without "<"

```
java ConsoleRobot commands_in_english.txt
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error; `Error: Could not find or load main class ConsoleRobot`

Comment: I have also tried `java -cp .:robotworld.jar ConsoleRobot < commands_in_english.txt` and `java -cp .:robotworld.jar ConsoleRobot commands_in_english.txt`. The former runs the program but the instructions I provide are not passed through and the latter also runs the program but it runs as normal with a prompt for me to enter the instructions through the terminal.